# How to show two matrices are similar

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I show that the following two matrices are similar

$A=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\quad$ and $\quad B =
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 4 \\
-1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$

I know they have same eigenvalue

But I am not sure how to show it. I am not sure how to find S so that $B=S^{-1}AS$ I have not learned the jordan canoical form or whatever it is called.

Comment: If you know that $A=S^{-1}BS$, then you are done. Otherwise write $SA=BS$ with $S=(s_{ij})$ and compute directly. You have to say, furthermore, over which domain.

Comment: Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are said to be *similar* if there exists a nonsingular matrix $S$ such that $A=S^{-1} B S$. So, if you already know that...

Comment: No I mean I do not know what S is

Comment: See [Conditions for matrix similarity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257322/conditions-for-matrix-similarity).

Comment: over the complex numbers.

Comment: It means there is a change of basis from one matrix to the other. So they are *similar* if they represent the same linear map under a different basis. This condition is presented exactly as the other comments described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need Jordan normal form. You only need linear equations and the determinant. Let $S=\begin{pmatrix} s_1 & s_3 \cr s_2 & s_4\end{pmatrix}$. Then $SA=BS$ is equivalent to the set of linear equations
$$
s_1 - 2s_2=0,\; s_1 + 2s_3 - 4s_4=0,\; s_2 + s_3 - 2s_4=0.
$$
Solve this over $K$, and do not forget to check $\det(S)=s_1s_4-s_2s_3\neq 0$. If there exists a solution, then $SA=BS$, i.e., $B=S^{-1}AS$, i.e., $A\sim B$.

Comment: Hmm So $SA=BS$ and you multipy both side by $SAS^{-1}$= $BSS^{-1}$

Comment: I thinkI also have to solve for $2s_1-4c_2=0$

Comment: Yes, but $2s_1-4s_2=0$ is the same equation as $s_1-2s_2=0$, if $2\neq 0$ in the field.